# Add Duktape to java.library.path

Tags: android

I want to add Duktape library to `java.library.path` to run some JUnit tests.

I tried using `-Djava.library.path="build/"` on VM options in Android Studio but I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no duktape in java.library.path` when running the test.

Also using `System.setProperty()` in the same test but I get the same error.

Comment: Why aren't you using `testCompile` (if you are executing unit tests) or `androidTestCompile` (if you are executing instrumentation tests) in your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: I already have `compile com.squareup.duktape:duktape-android:1.1.0` added to build.gradle. I need it also in the app, not only in the JUnit tests.

Comment: If it is in the app, it should already be in your unit and instrumentation test classpaths. If you are trying to use unit tests, note that you'll need x86 binaries, and I haven't tried using the NDK with unit tests, so YMMV.